# Display phone number using interpolated strings in C# 6.0

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I want to use the C# 6.0 interpolated string approach to format phone numbers. From the database, I get the phone number as a 7 digit value -- no special characters.

How do I produce the xxx-xxxx format using interpolated strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the custom number format `000-0000`.

```
var phoneNumber = 5551234;
var formatted = $"{phoneNumber:000-0000}" // "555-1234"
```

And with an optional extension, you could do this:

```
var phoneNumber = 5551234;
int? extension = 9876;
var formatted = $"{phoneNumber:000-0000}" // "555-1234"
if (extension != null)
    formatted = $"{formatted} Ext. {extension}"; // "555-1234 Ext. 9876"

// or alternatively
var formatted = $"{phoneNumber:000-0000}{(extension != null ? $" Ext. {extension}" : "")}";
```

Unfortunately, it's not very easy to include optional parts of a string within a single expression, but it's doable.  I wouldn't recommend trying to cram it all in though.  I'd opt for the more readable approach for your definition of "readable".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I may ask a follow up question: I also get phone extension in a separate variable but not all phone numbers have phone extensions. How can I evaluate null value for phoneExt and if not null add it to the same string using the c# 6.0 approach. I can easily do formatted += (phoneExt == null ? "" + "Ext. " + phoneExt.ToString()) but I want to master this new approach.

Comment: I figured out the answer to my follow up question:
var formatted = $"{phoneNumber:000-0000} {(string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneExt) ? "" : "Ext. " + phoneExt.ToString())}";

Comment: The way to look at it is that any expression within the braces (`{}`) is just any C# expression you could normally write, to which `ToString()` is called on.  If there is a custom format (denoted by the `:`), everything to the right of the `:` is the formatting string.  So essentially in this case, `$"{phoneNumber:000-00000}"` is effectively the same as `phoneNumber.ToString("000-0000")`. I wouldn't add the extension using this syntax as it's not really the best to handle because it tends to get ugly. But there are nicer ways to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: For some reason, the $"{phoneNumber:000-0000}"; is not formatting the text. BTW, phoneNumber is a string and I tried changing it $"{phoneNumber:###-####}"; but that didn't work either. I get the number without the hyphen in the middle. Any idea what may be causing the issue?

Comment: The format string only applies to numeric types. If it's a string, then you would need to do a different approach. Either parse it to a number and use the code here or do some string manipulation to get it in the format that you want.